# Duda con EF Framework y relación de entidades

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Me encuentro en desarrollo de una aplicación Angular + ASP.NET WEB API y tengo dudas de como funciona el tema de las relaciones.

Tengo un modelo de datos tal que así (oculto campos para simplificar)

```
public partial class Personas: TablaBaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        [JsonPropertyName("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    
        [JsonPropertyName("CodigoCotizacion")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false,ErrorMessage = "El código de cotización es obligatorio")]
        public string CodigoCotizacion { get; set; }
    
        [JsonPropertyName("Nombre")]
        public string? Nombre { get; set; }
    
        [JsonPropertyName("Apellidos")]
        public string? Apellidos { get; set; }
    
        public Provincias? provincia { get; set; } = null;
}
```

Y el modelo de Provincias lo tengo así.

```
public class Provincias: TablaBaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("Codigo")]
    public string Codigo { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [JsonPropertyName("Nombre")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }= string.Empty;


}
```

La idea es a cada persona asignarle una provincia para en un futuro poder sacar un listado.

En mi controlador tengo el siguiente código en el método Update

```
             Personas persona = await context.Personas.Where(x=>x.Id == modelo.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (persona != null)
            {
                persona.Codigo = modelo.Codigo;
                persona.Nif = modelo.Nif;
                persona.Nombre = modelo.Nombre;
                persona.Apellidos = modelo.Apellidos;
                persona.CodigoCotizacion = modelo.CodigoCotizacion;
                persona.Direccion = modelo.Direccion;
                persona.CodigoPostal = modelo.CodigoPostal;
                persona.Poblacion = modelo.Poblacion;
                persona.CodigoProvincia = modelo.CodigoProvincia;
                persona.FechaNacimiento = modelo.FechaNacimiento;
                persona.Edad = modelo.Edad;
                persona.Genero = modelo.Genero;
                persona.Telefono = modelo.Telefono;
                persona.Movil = modelo.Movil;
                persona.Email = modelo.Email;
                persona.provincia = modelo.provincia;
                persona.Empresa = modelo.Empresa;

            }

            context.Entry(persona).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
            await context.SaveChangesAsync()
```

El problema lo tengo en el SaveChangesAsync() el cual me indica que no puede insertar un registro de la entidad relacionada ya que existe uno con la misma clave.

La pregunta es, ¿Cómo hago para cambiar el State de la entidad relacionada a Modified?

Mi OnModelCreating() del DBContext lo tengo tal que así, y no sé si lo tengo bien configurado...

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Personas>().
            HasOne(p => p.provincia)
            .WithMany();


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Se debe establecer la relación entre los objetos y eso es algo que nos facilita EF. Mira este enlace hay varios ejemplos de como realizarlo

1. [Foreignkey-dataannotations-EF](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Solución:

```
public partial class Personas: TablaBaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    [JsonPropertyName("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("CodigoCotizacion")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false,ErrorMessage = "El código de cotización es obligatorio")]
    public string CodigoCotizacion { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("Nombre")]
    public string? Nombre { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("Apellidos")]
    public string? Apellidos { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("provincia")] //Nombre del objeto 
    public string? FkProvincia {get;set;} //Nombre del campo con el que se relaciona

    public Provincias provincia { get; set; } = null;

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Maria por la respuesta y el enlace facilitado. Me he fijado que en la clase Personas, además de indicar la clave foránea (tal como indican en el enlace), la propiedad provincia de mi modelo, debe ser Virtual para que a la hora de hacer una migración, este campo no se agregue a la tabla. La propiedad quedaría así: **public Virtual Provincias provincia { get; set; }**